# api 10 doesnt show on sdk manager

Tags: internal

my skd manager did not show any new versions to download, such as api 10. the "tools" link on top just said "manage addon sites" some suggested using that link. there is no "show only update" button on bottom, as this has been another answer given to others with this problem. one answerer said to use help menu, go to add new software, and add a particular webpage for the "add new site" link he gave. that download/install took over an hour and appears to be a trap as now i can't bring up the sdk or avd managers ("locataion has not been setup in preferences" message) or run my project anymore ("internal error occured" message). i have no idea how to fix the "internal error occured" error.

downloading that software seemed my only shot at getting the sdk to show the api 10, or any of the api's i didn't already have. should i just start completely over downloading eclipse now?

Answer (score 0):

i was hoping to just delete my question but the only option for that appeared to be "vote to delete" which sounded negative, like it would negatively affect my rating. i solved most of the problem by going to "help" and checking for updates. this downloaded some version 20.something updates that got rid of the "internal server" and "path not set" errors. now i get a "androidmanifest.xml file missing!" message even though the file is there as it has always been. so basically i got my issue changed to something i hope will be easier to solve, mainly getting eclipse to recognize my manifest file like it used to.